# TCP socket IO gets stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, socket.io

I want to implement a TCP client and use one thread to read with 
another thread to write. But for the read thread, I met an problem: "stuck while io gets bytes"

```
class SocketClientManager

  def initialize
   @socket = TCPSocket.new '192.168.3.86', 15533
   @response = nil
   @send = nil
   read
  end

  def read
    @response = Thread.new do
      loop {
        p "listen response from TCP server"
        # will stuck here while trying to "get bytes" from io in the code below
        header = @socket.gets(4).unpack('N')[0] 
        case header
        when case1 
        when case2 
        end 
      }
    end
  end
```

Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using recmsg_nonblock method can solve the problem.

```
readfds, writefds, exceptfds = select([@socket], nil, nil, 1)
p :r => readfds, :w => writefds, :e => exceptfds
if readfds
  p "we are in read status"
  #will not be blocked if not gets bytes from buffer
  hhh = @socket.recvmsg_nonblock(10000)  
else
  p "we are not in read status"
end
```